# Show Eur results with two decimal places

Tags: javascript

I am new to JavaScript so would appreciate help on this issue I have.

I have a booking form I have made and I have 3 Eur results that come up automatically following the  selection choices made (@Martina helped me with this challenge).

What I would like to do is get the results to show with 2 decimal places only - here is the link to the page I am talking about:
https://www.alpinemalta.net/oilandgaslibya/bookNow.html

I've tried looking through some of the posts in this forum and attempted some of the things but my newness to JS has not helped :(

Thanks again in advance for any help on this.

Cheers - Chris Brown

Comment: @Alnitak - WOW - How simple - thank you so much for your speedy response - I need to add 3% to the amount and this is what I did:


var pers3 = ((cost_E10.value*1.03).toFixed(2))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Number` class in Javascript has a [`.toFixed`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toFixed) method that does exactly what you require, e.g.:

```
var n = 234.1
var s = n.toFixed(2);  // s = "234.10"
```